# Subtract one day from DateTime object

Tags: c#

I want to substrate one day from my date, so that when my date is **30-7-2013** than I want **29-7-2013**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just use the [`AddDays`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays.aspx) method, remembering that it doesn't change the value it's called on - it *returns* a new `DateTime` value.

```
DateTime date = ...;
date = date.AddDays(-1);
```

Comment: CHEATING!! Omg, does that really works? Is that feature or smth undocumented?

Comment: @nsinreal: Of course it works, and it's quite clearly documented.

Comment: @JonSkeet:thanks jon id if I want to add week than  date = date.AddDays(+7); or any thing else?

Comment: @Mansinh: Well I wouldn't bother with the explicit `+`, but yes, that's fine.

Answer (score 6):

I am not familiar with windows phone development but you may try to use DateTime.AddDays(-1) method call. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) this call is supported by windows phone OS.

For example:

```
var today = DateTime.Now;
var yesterday = today.AddDays(-1);
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternative version:

```
DateTime date = ...;
date -= TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
```